# Assign values to ComboBox items from mySQL DB loop adds

Tags: vb.net, combobox

So I am able to get the comboBox populated with the proper list of "clientLocations".

However they all have a valueMember of 0; thus the issue at hand is properly assigning the value of the comboBox items to the database column (which is returned in the dataset) rather than just the name.

```
Private Sub updateClientLocationComboBox()
    'clear list
    comboBox_clientLocations_deviceList.Items.Clear()
    'get dataset from database
    Dim ds As DataSet = GetClientLocations(_objHost, CInt(comboBox_clients.SelectedValue))

    'force insert an "All Locations" datarow
    Dim allClientRow As DataRow = ds.Tables(0).NewRow
    allClientRow(0) = 0
    allClientRow(1) = "--All Locations--"
    ds.Tables(0).Rows.InsertAt(allClientRow, 0)

    'Check for table in dataset; if exist loop and populate comboBox
    If Not ds Is Nothing AndAlso ds.Tables.Count > 0 Then
        For Each A As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows
            comboBox_clientLocations_deviceList.Items.Add(A("Name").ToString)
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm reading you correctly, I think you want to do this with your DataSet:

```
If Not ds Is Nothing AndAlso ds.Tables.Count > 0 Then
    With comboBox_clientLocations_deviceList
        .DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
        .DisplayMember = "Name"
        .ValueMember = "WhateverCol(0)IsCalled"
    End With
End if
```

Then, with comboBox_clientLocations_deviceList the SelectedText and SelectedValue properties should work.